# Showing an Abelian group is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can someone please give me a hint to prove that if the order of the group $|G|=6$ and $G$ is abelian, then $G$ is cyclic?

My idea: if G is of order 6, then say, $x\in G$, then $|x|=|\lt x \gt|=6$
, then $G $ is cyclic? I do not know if this is true

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See also http://lincoln.sjfc.edu/~gwildenberg/abstract_algebra/abelian-6.html.

Comment: @Ihf can you please help me understand a comment there? someone has commented that if $n=p_1...p_k$, where $p_i$ is prime, then the group is cyclic.

Comment: may I ask in the chat @Ihf?

Comment: @Ihf Ok, I am posting now. Thanks :)

Comment: @Ihf I did http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739581/an-abelian-group-of-order-n-is-cyclic