# An Abelian group of order n is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the link below, someone has made a comment that an abelian group of order $n$ with $n=p_1...p_n$, where $p_1...p_n$ are primes, is cyclic. Can someone please explain why this is the case?

Thanks in advance!

[An abelian group of order $n$ with $n=p_1...p_n$, where $p_1...p_n$ are primes, is cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370265/an-abelian-group-of-order-6-has-an-element-of-order-6)

Comment: You can use the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups...but that is kind of a sledgehammer. To avoid the sledgehammer, you can generalize the proof in that post. Use Cauchy's theorem to produce an element of order $n$.

Comment: The condition $n=p_1p_2\cdots p_n$ is impossible since $p_1p_2\cdots p_n>n$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: I think the $n's$ are supposed to be different? That's how I was reading it anyway.

Comment: @JohnMartin Yes, but better to ask what exactly the question is.

Comment: Use Sylow's first theorem  to decompose the abelian group as a direct sum of its sylow-p subgroups and use the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_{m} \oplus  \mathbb{Z}_{n} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ whenever $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, along with induction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hard part is the existence of elements of order $p_i$ for each $i$. This follows from [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), which has a simple induction proof for finite abelian groups.

Once you have those elements, the result follows by repeated application of this general fact:

> In an abelian group, if $a$ has order $m$ and $b$ has order $n$, and $m$ and $n$ are coprime, then $ab$ has order $mn$.

Indeed, if $(ab)^k=1$ then $a^k=b^{-k} \in \langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle = 1$ because $m$ and $n$ are coprime. Therefore, $a^k=b^k=1$ and so $k$ is a multiple of $lcm(m,n)=mn$.

Comment: So then, for any abelian group, whose order i can decompose into distinct primes, is cyclic?

Comment: @FrankBooth, yes.